# Possible to append new ListViewSubItem to ListViewSubItem[] in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, listview

My code works. But I've hardcoded some things.

I have dictionary where `Keys` are filenames and `Values` are lists of attributes for the filename.

On my form I have a `ListView` where I've already added all necessary columns in another part of the code.

In my code below, I'm having to extract attributes by index (e.g. `first = mydict[file.Name][0];`) then hardcoding these under the `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]` object, one by one.

I'd like instead to loop through all attributes in a `Values` list and add them that way so it's more dynamic.

I did try something like `subItems.Append(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, second))`. I got no error, but noticed the values weren't being added in the form

Edit: Should note that there are quite a lot attributes associated with the files, which is why I'm looking to do it with a loop instead of the way I've done it. Also not every filename in my list view will be in the dictionary. If it's not there, I'll just leave all the extra attribute columns (e.g. `first` and `second`) blank.

**My Code:**

```
    foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
        string first = "";
        string second = "";

        if (mydict.ContainsKey(file.Name)) 
        {
            first = mydict[file.Name][0];
            second = mydict[file.Name][1];
        }

        subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
            { 
                // Okay for the first 3 items here to be hardcoded in
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString()),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.FullName),

                // Would like these two added via a loop
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, first),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, second)
            };

        item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

**Pseudo code of what I'd want:**

```
    foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);

        subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
            { 
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString()),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, file.FullName)
            };

       // Psuedocode
       if (mydict.ContainsKey(file.Name))
          {
            foreach(value in mydict[file.Name])
              {
               subItems.Append(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, value))
              }
          }
        item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

EDIT: This may be working...

```
    foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
        item.Text = file.Name;
        item.SubItems.Add("File");
        item.SubItems.Add(file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString());
        item.SubItems.Add(file.FullName);
        if (mydict.ContainsKey(file.Name))
        {
            foreach(string x in mydict[file.Name])
            {
                item.SubItems.Add(x);
            }       
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>`?

Comment: I've only just starting using C# so not aware of that. How that work in this context?

Comment: `subItems = new List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>` then add other items with `subItems.Add(.....)`

Comment: Having a few issues with this, particularly with this line `item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems)`. Would I initialise `subItems` as `List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>[]`

Comment: No `[]`, the type is just `List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>`

Comment: Still having some issues. The line `subItems = new List<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>;` needs a `()` at the end for me to avoid any issues, but then the line `item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems); receives a `cannot convert...` type error.

Comment: It doesn't need a `()` if you still have that 3 items in a `{...}` after it. The error can be fixed with `item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems.ToArray());`.